# Getting R package 'bsts' to work on AWS Sagemaker Notebook Instance Python

Tags: python, r, amazon-web-services, amazon-sagemaker

Just wondering if anyone has been able to get a Python + R kernel working on AWS Sagemaker Notebook instance?

The reason I'm asking is so I can use a python environment to run R packages within, specifically 'bsts' and 'boom'.

Is there a way to create a kernel that has both Python + R installed?

Comment: [rPy2](https://rpy2.github.io/) seems to be a good solution if you want to run R within a python kernel.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using SageMaker Notebook Instances, there is a prebuilt R Kernel you can make use of.

Kindly see this [link](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sagemaker/latest/dg/r-guide.html) for more information.

If there are packages you wish to install you can look at running:
`install.packages("<packageName>")`